# php conexión con servidor

Tags: php, azure

Necesito conectar mi web a una base de datos alojada en un servidor de Microsoft Azure. El caso es que actualmente lo hago con mysqli orientado a procedimientos y Azure me genera el código de la conexión para PDO. Estoy tratando de usar los datos que me dan para adaptarlo a programación orientada a procedimientos. El código que ellos me generan:

```
// PHP Data Objects(PDO) Sample Code:
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = tcp:minombre.database.windows.net,1433; 
    Database = nombrebdd", "nombreusuario", "contrasena");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print("Error connecting to SQL Server.");
    die(print_r($e));
}

// SQL Server Extension Sample Code:
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "nombre@nombree", "pwd" => "
contrasena", "Database" => "nombredb", "LoginTimeout" => 30, 
"Encrypt" => 1, "TrustServerCertificate" => 0);

$serverName = "tcp:minombre.database.windows.net,1433";

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Y lo que estoy tratando de hacer, y sin mucho éxito por ahora, es:

```
$servername = "tcp:minombre.database.windows.net,1433";
  $username = "nombreusuario";
  $password = "contrasena";
  $dbname = "nombrebdd";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT id FROM productos";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "Usuario" . $row["id"];
      }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
  $conn->close();
```

Si alguien sabe decirme lo que estoy haciendo mal se lo agradecería :D

Comment: Hola.¿Y por qué quieres pasarlo a MySQLi, ya que Azurre te da la info para PDO...? Además, es mejor PDO que MySQLi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría el uso de PDO, el cual ofrece más posibilidades que MySQLi.

**Pero** se requiere tener tu PDO bien configurado, para tales fines lo mejor es tener tu propia clase PDO.

Un ejemplo sencillo de clase PDO, con algunas funciones personalizadas:

---

### Db.php

```
<?php
    class Db 
    {

    private $host      = 'localhost';
    private $user      = 'tu-usuario';
    private $dbname    = 'nombre-bd';
    private $pass      = 'password';
    private static $instance;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // DSN: cadena de conexión
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

        /* Opciones
            * Muy importante, para tener una buena conexión PDO

        */    
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true, //establecer a false si no se quieren conexiones persistentes
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, //no cambiar nunca
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //no cambiar nunca
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'" //juego de caracteres
        );

        // Crea nueva instancia de PDO
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        // Captura los errores
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }



    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance == null) 
        {
            $className = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $className();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }



     /******************************************** MÉTODOS IMPRESCINDIBLES */

    //Recibe las consultas
    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    //Ejecuta las consultas
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    //Devuelve resultados de la consulta en PDO::FETCH_ASSOC 
    //Se puede cambiar o agregar otro método con otro tipo de resultado
    public function resultset()
    {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

    //Envía los datos por separado para proteger de la inyección SQL
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null)
    {
        if (is_null($type)) 
        {
            switch (true) 
            {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    /********************************************** FIN MÉTODOS IMPRESCINDIBLES




    /******************************************** MÉTODOS OPCIONALES */

    //Devuelve el último registro insertado
    public function lastInsertId()
    {
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    //Obtiene un registro simple
    public function single()
    {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }


    //Devuelve un solo valor, columna o 0
    public function valor()
    {
        $this->execute();
        $valor=$this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
        return (empty($valor)) ? 0 : $valor;

    }

    //Verifica si un registro existe devolviendo true o false
    public function si_existe()
    {
        $this->execute();
        if ($this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
     /**********************************************/

}

?>
```

---

### Ejemplo de uso

En cualquier parte donde quieras usar la conexión:

1. Incluir el archivo de conexión

   `include_once("Db.php")`

   Indicar la ruta correcta donde se encuentra
2. Crear instancia de la clase y objeto conexión:

   `$oDb = new Db();
   $oPDO=$oDb->getInstance();`
3. Consultar

   `$oPDO->query("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE col1=:col1 AND col2=:col2");
   $oPDO->bind(':col1', $col1);
   $oPDO->bind(':col2', $col2);
   $arrDatos = $oPDO->resultset();`

   Las variables `$col1 y $col2` serían datos obtenidos desde fuera que se pasarían a la BD separados de la instrucción SQL. No hay que preocuparse del tipo de dato, la clase se ocupa de ello (ver método `bind` de la misma).
   El método `resultset()` devuelve un array asociativo de nuestros datos, listo para ser recorrido y presentado en cualquier parte del programa.