# Duda de string de conexion entre azure y php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, azure

Saludos, tengo una pregunta:

Tengo una base de datos mysql en azure y quiero conectarla con php pero no se como.
Tengo este comando pero no se por que reemplazar donde dice "localhost" y $db.
Gracias de antemano.

```
<?php
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "db";

    $db = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");

    echo"Great work!"

?>
```

Comment: Creo que la respuesta a esta pregunta  [php conexión con servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67798/29967) puede servirte, era un caso similar al tuyo, usando Azurre.

Comment: localhost => direccion de la base de datos (IP)

db => nombre de la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Debes buscar en el portal de Azure el servicio de MySQL, en caso sea nativo de Azure. Si es administrado por ClearBD debes ingresar al portal de ClearDB y dentro estará el nombre del servidor y base de datos.