# Error al conectar con la BDD mediante una clase

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy usando una clase que me proporcionó un usuario en una pregunta que publiqué hace un tiempo.

El caso es que mediante esta clase puedo hacer la conexión a la base de datos y realizar consultas, etc.

Estaba haciendo un test de conexión cuando al ejecutar una consulta me ha aparecido el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined property: Db::$stmt in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\datos_conexion.php on line 94
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on
>   null in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\datos_conexion.php:94 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php(22): Db->bind(':user', 'gmarsi') #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\datos_conexion.php on line 94

El código que uso es éste:

```
<?php 

require("datos_conexion.php");

$dbObj = new Db();
$pdoObj = $dbObj -> getInstance();

$user = '';
$name = 'marcos';
$user = 'gmarsi';
$data = 'SELECT User_User FROM users WHERE User_Punc > 0 ';

if($user != ''){
    $data .= " AND User_User = :user ";
    $pdoObj -> bind(':user', 'gmarsi');
} 

if($name != ''){
    $data .= " AND User_Name = :name ";
    $pdoObj -> bind(':name', $name);
} 

echo $data;
$pdoObj -> query($data);
$resultado = $pdoObj ->resultset();

foreach($resultado as $row){
    echo '<br>'.$row['User_User'];
}

?>
```

Y la clase en cuestión es ésta:

```
<?php
class Db 
{

private $host      = 'localhost';
private $user      = 'admin';
private $dbname    = 'baseDeDatos';
private $pass      = 'contraseña';
private static $instance;

public function __construct()
{
    // DSN: cadena de conexión
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

    /* Opciones
        * Muy importante, para tener una buena conexión PDO

    */    
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, //establecer a false si no se quieren conexiones persistentes
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, //no cambiar nunca
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //no cambiar nunca
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'" //juego de caracteres
    );

    // Crea nueva instancia de PDO
    try{
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Captura los errores
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}



public static function getInstance()
{
    if (self::$instance == null) 
    {
        $className = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $className();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}



 /******************************************** MÉTODOS IMPRESCINDIBLES */

//Recibe las consultas
public function query($query)
{
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

//Ejecuta las consultas
public function execute()
{
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}

//Devuelve resultados de la consulta en PDO::FETCH_ASSOC 
//Se puede cambiar o agregar otro método con otro tipo de resultado
public function resultset()
{
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

//Envía los datos por separado para proteger de la inyección SQL
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null)
{
    if (is_null($type)) 
    {
        switch (true) 
        {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

/********************************************** FIN MÉTODOS IMPRESCINDIBLES




/******************************************** MÉTODOS OPCIONALES */

//Devuelve el último registro insertado
public function lastInsertId()
{
    return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}

//Obtiene un registro simple
public function single()
{
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}


//Devuelve un solo valor, columna o 0
public function valor()
{
    $this->execute();
    $valor=$this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    return (empty($valor)) ? 0 : $valor;

}

//Verifica si un registro existe devolviendo true o false
public function si_existe()
{
    $this->execute();
    if ($this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
 /**********************************************/

}

?>
```

Dejo el enlace a la respuesta donde obtuve esta clase, ya que el usuario hizo un ejemplo de uso. [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67778/php-conexi%C3%B3n-con-servidor)

Comment: Tienes un error en la clase, haciendo uso de `$error` sin haber sido definida y, por otro lado, si capturas la excepción y asignas el error, deberías comprobar si hubo o no error durante la conexión. Lo mismo pasa con `$stmt`. Tampoco estás comprobando si la consulta se preparó bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes arreglar el primer error (*Undefined property: `Db::$stmt`*), debido a que no está definida la propiedad de la clase:

```
<?php
class Db
{
    /* Definimos propiedades públicas */
    public $error = false, $stmt = false;
    /* ... */
```

Para solucionar el segundo error hay que blindar el código que usa la clase y llamar primero a `query` que a `bind` (el primero prepara la consulta y establece el valor de `stmt` y el segundo hace uso de `stmt` para establecer el valor de las variables en la consulta preparada):

```
<?php

require("datos_conexion.php");

/* Para que funcione como fue diseñado hay llamar al método estático */
$pdoObj = \Db::getInstance();
if ($pdoObj->error !== false) {
    die($pdoObj->error);
}

$user = '';
$name = 'marcos';
$user = 'gmarsi';
$data = 'SELECT User_User FROM users WHERE User_Punc > 0 ';

/* Antes de hacer uso de bind debes preparar la consulta */
$pdoObj->query($data);
if ($pdoObj->stmt === false) {
    die('Ocurrió un error y la clase no permite ver el motivo');
}

/* Ahora sí podemos hacer uso de los bind */
if ($user != '') {
    $data .= " AND User_User = :user ";
    $pdoObj -> bind(':user', 'gmarsi');
}

if ($name != '') {
    $data .= " AND User_Name = :name ";
    $pdoObj -> bind(':name', $name);
}

$resultado = $pdoObj ->resultset();

foreach ($resultado as $row) {
    echo '<br>'.$row['User_User'];
}
```